# Finding oldest packages that satisfy dependencies

Tags: linux, yum, rpm

I need a way to determine which packages would need to be installed to satisfy the dependencies for a package.

At the moment, I'm doing:

```
repoquery -R --resolve <package>
```

but I need the results to return the *oldest* versions that satisfy dependencies, not the most recent. Are there any repo query tools that do this?

Comment: Why do you want the oldest version?  Why aren't you letting yum resolve the dependencies for you?  What is the package you are trying to install?

Comment: It's a very controlled environment in which we have local mirrors of repositories which we pull packages from to populate local repos. I ask repoquery "if I want to install package 'x', what other packages will need installing" and copy all packages into the local repo. (this is scripted, not a manual process). 

At the moment, repoquery says 'x-1.0.0.rpm needs y-2.0.1.rpm' but the version of 'y' in the local repo (and also in mirrors of upstream repos) already satisfies the dependencies of 'x'). I don't want updated versions unless they are *definitely* required.

Comment: Just a note to say I never found a solution to this question and ended up rewriting the code so that it calculated dependencies itself instead of trying to use repoquery / yum.